# Why is the Big O notation of merge sort not O(n) when it requires looping through every element in the array to merge?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, runtime, big-o

Let's say I have an unsorted array Unsorted_Arr= [2, 8, 1, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4].

Right before the very last pass of merging, I would have two arrays, Arr_Left = [1, 2, 3, 8] and Arr_Right = [4, 5, 6, 7]. To merge them, I would need to iterate through all the n elements of Arr_Right fully, and iterate through n-1 elements of Arr_Left. In total, I would have traversed through n-1 elements of the original Unsorted_Arr. Drop the -1, and I have a time-complexity of O(n) for the merge.

While I understand why the recursive portion of merge sort is log n, since our code contains a portion of code that runs at O(n), shouldn't the worst case scenario of a merge sort be O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

But those two arrays are themselves not necessarily already sorted, so you have to split them and then re-merge them as well.  And you'd have to repeat that down until there was only one or zero elements in each array (because a 1 or 0 element array is always sorted) and then re-merge them all.

And at each level, that's at least `2*n` operations (for all of the split arrays at that level), which is `O(n)` for *each* level.

So how many levels deep would you have to go with the splitting before every array was only 1 or 0 in length?  That's `Log(n)`.

Combining the number of levels that you have to split and then re-merge all of the sublists (`O(Log(n))`) with how many operations have to be performed at each level (`O(n)`) becomes: `O(Log(n)) * O(n)` which reduces to `O(n*Log(n))`.